# SQL query for extracting accounts whose last load date is not equal to today

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I seem to have some issue in the query and need your help.

I have 2 tables:

1st table contains Bank account details - account number, status etc - bankacc

2nd table stores name of the statement and the load date on which the statement is imported - bankstm

I am trying to write a query that will populate only those bank accounts whose statement was not imported as of today date.

Date format in database - `2020-01-17 00:00:00.000`

Code that i have tried:

```
SELECT b.bank_acc as Bank_Account, max(b.date_ld) as Load_Date from bankstm b 
where  b.date_ld < CAST(GETDATE() AS DATE) and 
b.bank_acc in (select a.acc_no from bankacc a where a.in_use = 'Y' and a.analyse03 = '1517') 
group by b.bank_acc
```

This code populates all the records from previous date whereas most of them statements loaded today.

I also attempted the code with `'='` or `'<>'` or `'>'` based on the queries raised previously in stack overflow. But nothing seems to be giving me the correct result.

So finally i am raising it for experts to help me out.

Comment: Can you provide sample data please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to apply the date filter on the max.
I cast the max(b.date_ld) to date in case its datetime format

```
SELECT b.bank_acc as Bank_Account, max(b.date_ld) as Load_Date from bankstm b 
where   
b.bank_acc in (select a.acc_no from bankacc a where a.in_use = 'Y' and a.analyse03 = '1517') 
group by b.bank_acc
having cast(max(b.date_ld) as date) < CAST(GETDATE() AS DATE)
```

Answer (score 0):

first of all you can improve your query with join and avoid using sub query.

```
SELECT b.bank_acc as Bank_Account, max(b.date_ld) as Load_Date 
FROM bankstm AS b 
LEFT JOIN bankacc AS ba ON b.bank_acc = ba.acc_no
WHERE ba.in_use = 'Y' 
AND ba.analyse03 = '1517'
GROUP BY b.bank_acc
HAVING CAST(MAX(b.date_ld) AS DATE) < CAST(GETDATE() AS DATE)
```

Comment: CAST, not CASR - it won't let me submit an edit due to the low number of characters.

Comment: Thank you for your response.. unfortunately there seems to be some issue with the query..
SQL error (147):  An aggregate may not appear in the WHERE clause

Thank you for your help though...

Comment: you can move last where clause to having

Answer (score 0):

You can modify your statement to use a not exists if your only criteria is that the record doesn't have a corresponding entry for today's date as a load date. 
If the criteria is different, may require modification.

```
SELECT [b].[bank_acc] AS     [bank_account]
     , MAX([b].[date_ld]) AS [load_date]
FROM   bankstm AS b
WHERE  NOT EXISTS
(
    SELECT 1
    FROM   [bankstm] AS [bb]
    WHERE  [b].[bank_acc] = [bb].[bank_acc] AND 
           TRY_CONVERT(DATE, [bb].[date_ld]) = TRY_CONVERT(DATE, GETDATE())
)
AND EXISTS
(
    SELECT 1
    FROM   [bankacct] a
    WHERE  b.bank_acc = a.bank_acc and a.in_use = 'Y' and a.analyse03 = '1517'
)
GROUP BY b.bank_acc
;
```

Comment: Thank you for your response.. efforts are much appreciated.. but i guess zip provided a quick fix to the solution.. many many thanks for your efforts..

Comment: It happens :) Thanks for following up and marking his answer correctly.

Answer (score 0):

I would use `not exists`:

```
select ba.*
from bankacc ba
where ba.in_use = 'Y' and
      ba.analyse03 = '1517' and
      not exists (select 1
                  from bankstm bs
                  where bs.bank_acc = ba.acc_no and
                        bs.date_ld = convert(date, getdate())
                 );
```

For performance, you want indexes on `bankacc(in_use, analyse03, acc_no)` and `bankstm(bank_acc, date_ld)`.

Comment: I only managed to sneak in 20 seconds before you this time, Gordon! You're so active here, thanks for all of the answers you post. I noticed the curdate(), and I've never seen that before - it doesn't seem to work when I try it. Is that compatible with SQL server?

Comment: Thank you for your response.. Unfortunately.. i get the below error:
SQLerror (195) : currdate is not a recognized buildin function name

Thank you for the response though...

Comment: @SeanBrookins . . . I must have misread the tag.  That is in MySQL.

Comment: That makes sense; I've only just started exploring MySQL so I didn't recognize it.Thanks for the follow up.